# How to do efficient cached JDBC Lookups in Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark

we need to enrich incoming Kafka DStream data using a JDBC-lookup. For every Kafka message we need to look up information in some lookup table via JDBC.

This is rather simple to do in Spark Streaming, as long as the lookup table is small or the lookup data is static (or changing slowly over time). In such case the script can load up the entire lookup table into Spark. After some expiration time it just needs to refresh the lookup data doing another full reload.

The problem is that our lookup table is huge (e.g. we cannot do full reloads every 10 seconds) and is changing over time (e.g refreshing lookup data every hour results in too out-dated lookup data), the above approach no longer works.

I was thinking about the following high-level logic (inspired from some threads on Storm streaming):

1. For every Spark Streaming micro-batch we extract all lookup keys
2. For all lookup keys we check whether the lookup data is available already (cache) and whether this cached information has not expired (e.g. 60s expiration time), yet.
3. For any lookup keys not found in cache (or expired), we send batched prepared JDBC Statements to the database to fetch the missing lookup data:
    SELECT c1, c2, c3 FROM ... WHERE k1 in (?,?,?,...)
    to minimize the number of JDBC round-trips.
4. At this point we have up-to-date lookup data for all lookup keys and can perform the lookup operation

How should this be done on Spark Streaming? Would Spark State DStreams be the right way to go? Or other design approaches?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered doing incremental updates from the source SQL server into a simpler key/value store?

e.g. for each INSERT or UPDATE to SQL, do an update to a Redis instance which you can then query?

There's various tools that can do this based on the transaction logs from the DB, e.g. [BottledWater](https://martin.kleppmann.com/2015/04/23/bottled-water-real-time-postgresql-kafka.html) for Postgres to Kafka replication

Comment: Thank you Ewan, replicate to key/value store is not in our consideration due to some other reason,  but the article is really good